# What ZFC axiom guarantees the existence of a domain set and a range set?

Tags: set-theory

Suppose we are working with the Kuratowski definition of ordered pairs, and that a relation is a set of ordered pairs. What axiom guarantees that $\operatorname{dom}(R) = \{ x : \exists y \langle x, y \rangle \in R\}$ and $\operatorname{ran}(R) = \{y : \exists x \langle x, y \rangle \in R\}$ are sets? I think that the axiom of replacement should be enough, but I am not so sure.

Comment: I am trying to imagine encountering a relation where I do not know the set of departure and the set of destination. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Formal_definition But thought provoking question.

Comment: @CopyPasteIt Maybe the relation $n \mathrel{R} \kappa$ defined by $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\kappa$ is a (von Neumann) cardinal, and there exist exactly $n$ infinite cardinals $\in \kappa$?  If you can find the range of this $R$, you can define $\aleph_\omega$ as the sup of the cardinals in this range...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of replacement, you could use the axioms of union and of separation (unless of course you treat separation as a consequence of replacement rather than an axiom).  With Kuratowski's definition of ordered pairs, if $R$ is a relation then $\bigcup\bigcup R$ is the union of the domain and range of $R$,from which you can extract the domain and the range by separation.

The reason for pointing out this alternative approach is that it works even in Zermelo set theory, which is weaker than Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory.

Comment: One might wonder why we need Replacement, then. But we need it because it guarantees that definable functions with a domain are in fact functions in the universe (as opposed to proper classes).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Right. The proof in Zermelo set theory that the domain and range of a relation are sets depends on the relation's being a set to begin with.  (As far as I know, the original motivation for introducing the axiom(s) of replacement was that Zerrmelo set theory can't prove the existence of $\beth_\omega$.)

Answer (score 3):

You're right that that'll work (though as another answer mentions, it's not the only usable approach). Given a relation $R$, replacement maps any $(x,\,y)\in R$ to $x$, giving the domain. The range follows similarly. All you need is a definition of ordered pairs that implies their coordinates are uniquely defined.

Comment: Would this formula $\exists c(x = \langle y, c \rangle)$ be enough to legitimate  the definition of domain, with the replacement axiom (take an instance of the axiom, with this formula as $\phi$)?

Comment: I think I made myself clearer now, sorry for the nonsensical comment.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Yes, that'll do.